# "I will shoot you a message, if you ___ available, we can play!"

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

> I will shoot you a message, if you ___ available, we can play!

So, what verb should I use here? "were" or "are"?

Comment: You need a full stop ('period') after either "message" or "available". What are you trying to say? (I don't know how you 'shoot' messages but perhaps your playmate does.)

Comment: You need the present tense of the verb: "If you are available we can play." (You could also say, "If you **were** available we **could** play.")

Comment: @OldBrixtonian The thing that I’m trying to say is that in the possible future, if you become available, we can play. Cause once, in the ELL, they told me that I shouldn’t use `were` as it shows something that could be possible but it didn’t happen and this will show a possible thing that if had happened, the result would happen and from then on, I got so confused over using these verbs cause from the things I have learnt, I know that I can say: If in future you `were` available, we `could` play. So is it correct to use `were` for future? And `are` is correct when we’re talking about future?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian And yeah , we say shoot a message .

Comment: It's great that you're wanting to use perfect English like "If you were available we could play". But you **could** just say, "If/when/whenever you're available, we can play." "*Is it correct to use **were** for the future?*" Sometimes, but there are easier ways to talk about the future. The Subjunctive Mood is difficult to explain and explanations are often daunting! It's probably easier just to memorize any examples you come across. Then you will get a feel for them. That's what I would do if I **were** you.

Comment: We don't shoot messages, though we do shoot the messenger :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thanks for the examples. Yeah, I was thinking that I was given a wrong warning about using `were` and `could` and other verbs like that for future tenses as I remember using them a lot. So, as an example, if I want to say `If you get to pick up the phone, we can talk.`, I feel like it’s conveying a message that’s urging the other person to pick up the phone so I would rather say `If you could pick up the phone, we could talk` to convey a possible future, in which you do pick the phone and we talk. So which sentence can be more correct? Sorry, I’m asking a lot of questions

Comment: Let's forget "get to". Its meaning is slippery! "If you **would** do (something)" is a standard, polite request. "If you **could** do (something)" suggests the other person might lack the *ability* to do it. BUT "Would you help me" and "Could you help me" are equally polite. OK. First read about **Modal verbs**: These two pages keep it simple: [1](https://blogs.transparent.com/english/english-modal-verbs-how-and-why-to-use-them/), [2](https://blogs.transparent.com/english/english-could-vs-would/).

Comment: ....Once you're clear about those (and not before!) move on to Subjunctive Mood. "If you'd pick up the phone we could talk" is fairly standard but sounds slightly p****d off. I don't know your relationship, but I might say, "Do pick up the phone. It'd be great to talk/I'd love to talk." Or just, "Let's talk, if you have time."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I see. I get what you mean. I’ll keep it simple as you said. The main thing I had in mind was that the `If you would pick up the phone, we could talk.` is about past that never happened but `Can it be used to refer to future?` I mean in the future, as you said `Pick up the phone, it’d be great to talk` isn’t subjunctive so it’s going to carry a different meaning. For example, let me say, `If you could free him tomorrow, it’ll be great!` is politely asking the person to free the target. `If you could play, we could have a good time` is about past, is it understandable for future?

Comment: I don’t know why but still have a feeling that tells me my structures are `Conditional II`s that are referring to future that is wrong because conditionals refer to past! I’m sorry if I’m being dumb or something but as soon as I get over this, it’ll all be great 

Comment: *If you would pick up the phone, we could talk* is NOT about the past: it's about the future. *If you could free him tomorrow, it WOULD be great* is politely asking...*If you could free him it willl...* is nonsense. These are all good: "If you free him it will...", "If you can free him it will..." "If you could... it would..." "If you would...it would..." "If you had freed him, it would have..."

Comment: I've changed my mind about the order in which you should study these. FIRST study the **conditionals**: [here](https://7esl.com/english-conditionals/), THEN the **modal verbs** (1 and 2 above), THEN (maybe) the **Subjunctive Mood**. Good luck.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I see. Great. I’ll check those out now. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it. If you’d like, maybe add your stuff as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer...